# std::get_time not working correctly in VS 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, std

The following code does not throw an exception when built and run using VS 2017. Note the month in the date is not valid.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string invalidMonth = "2013-13-02T19:58:55Z";

    std::tm datetime = {};
    std::istringstream iss(invalidMonth);
    iss >> std::get_time(&datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");

    if (iss.fail())
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Invalid value '" << invalidMonth << "'\n";
        throw std::runtime_error(oss.str());
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "No error\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The value of `datetime` after parsing is:

```
tm_sec  55  int
tm_min  58  int
tm_hour 19  int
tm_mday 2   int
tm_mon  0   int
tm_year 113 int
tm_wday 0   int
tm_yday 0   int
tm_isdst    0   int
```

This code throws an exception when built and run using VS 2013.

Comment: What you expect to get when your string date contains the month 13? January 02 2014?

Comment: Did you read the question @S.M.?

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly.

`std::get_time` throws an exception `ios_base::failure` if the resulting error state flag is not `ios_base::iostate::goodbit` and member `std::basic_ios::exceptions` was set to throw for that state.

Check the value returned by `iss.exceptions()` to see which of `eofbit`, `failbit` and `badbit` are set.

This is a common case for all stream operations, not only for `std::get_time`.